# Getting error android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, zxing

I am testing zxing barcode scanner from github https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner .

I have fragment A, Fragment ScanFragment and fragment ProductDetail. Fragment ScanFragment has SimpleScannerFragment which contains code for barcode scanner. I am using replace fragment transaction and putting fragment in backstack.

I go from fragments in following direction.

Fragment A -> ScanFragment -> Fragment Product detail -> ScanFragment

Then, I press back to get back in same way,
ScanFragment -> Fragment Product detail -> ScanFragment(Error here)

```
Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at np.com.ddm1.myandroidtoolshelper.BarcodeTest.BarcodeScanner.ScanFragment.onCreateView(ScanFragment.java:56)
```

Fragment A consist only button to pass to ScanFragment. 
Fragment Product detail has button which opens ScanFragment to get barcode Scanner.

I need help on following things. 
1. I have used replace fragment transaction here. But I am not sure if I should use add or replace fragment here. In which scenario we should use add or replace?
2. Should I make second fragment "ScanFragment2" to avoid this error? or I can use same ScanFragment repeatedly.

ScanFragment :

```
public class ScanFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "ScanFragment";

View view;
TextView textViewToolbarTitle;
ImageView imageViewBack;
LinearLayout linearLayout_Skip;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PrintLog.showTag(TAG,"== onCreate ==");
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    PrintLog.showTag(TAG,"== onViewCreated ==");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    PrintLog.showTag(TAG,"--- onCreateView ---");
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bc_fragment_scan,container,false);
    ButterKnife.setDebug(true);
    ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
    initializeUI();
    onClick();
    return view;
}

private void initializeUI(){
    textViewToolbarTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewToolbarTitle);
    imageViewBack = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewBack);

    textViewToolbarTitle.setText("Scan Fragment");
    imageViewBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    linearLayout_Skip = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_skip);
}

private void onClick(){
    linearLayout_Skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            releaseCamera();
            ProductDetailFormFragment productDetailFormFragment  = new ProductDetailFormFragment();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.mainFragment, productDetailFormFragment).addToBackStack("scan_fragment").commit();
        }
    });
}

private void releaseCamera(){
    SimpleScannerFragment simpleScannerFragment = (SimpleScannerFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.scanner_fragment);
    simpleScannerFragment.releaseCamera();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    PrintLog.show("CALLED ON ACTIVITY RESULT");
}
}
```

SimpleScannerFragment :

```
public class SimpleScannerFragment extends 
Fragment implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
private static final String TAG = "SimpleScannerFragment";
private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
ScanListener scanListener;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity());
    PrintLog.showTag(TAG,"===  onCreateView() ==");
    return mScannerView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    PrintLog.showTag(TAG,"== onResume() ==");
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera();
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    PrintLog.showTag(TAG,"== handleResult() ==");
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(SimpleScannerFragment.this);
        }
    }, 2000);

    //--- case for calling from different fragments
    if(getArguments() != null){
        if(getArguments().getString("parent_fragment").equals("product_details")){
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            scanListener.onScanComplete(rawResult.getText());
        }
    }else{
        ProductDetailFormFragment productDetailFormFragment  = new ProductDetailFormFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("serial_number",rawResult.getText());
        productDetailFormFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.mainFragment, productDetailFormFragment).addToBackStack("scan_fragment").commit();
    }
}

public void releaseCamera(){
    PrintLog.showTag(TAG,"== releaseCamera() ==");
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
}

public interface ScanListener{
    public void onScanComplete(String serialNumber);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    PrintLog.showTag(TAG,"== onPause() ==");
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    PrintLog.showTag(TAG,"== onDestroyView() ==");
}
}
```

ScanFragment layout :

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:clickable="true"
>

<fragment android:name="np.com.ddm1.myandroidtoolshelper.BarcodeTest.BarcodeScanner.SimpleScannerFragment"
    android:id="@+id/scanner_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Remove this line "imageViewBack = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewBack);" because you are already bind this variable here @BindView(R.id.imageViewBack) ImageView imageViewBack; so you don't need to initialize it again.

Comment: Why you write imageViewBack.setOnClickListener() twice. Also remove the linearLayout_Skip = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_skip); this line which already bind here @BindView(R.id.linearLayout_skip) LinearLayout linearLayout_Skip;

Comment: @andy, sorry bro.. those were copy paste mistake. Anyway, leaving those UI mistakes, can you help providing view on those 2 questions I asked? When to use add/replace on fragment transaction? And, If I can use same ScanFragment (containing barcode scanner code) multiple times like shown above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

from the xml file in the `<FrameLayout>` tag

Comment: the error is related with SimpleScannerFragment. If I removed this fragment, then error goes ...